# String to int array [][] - JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a board game define as

```
boardArray = new int[4][4];
```

and I have a string in this format:

```
String s = "[[0,0,2,0],[0,0,2,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]"
```

Is there a way to put it in the int array? Consider that it should look like this

```
[0,0,2,0]
[0,0,2,0]
[0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: apply `String[] chopped = s.substring(2,s.length()-2).split("\\],\\[");` and then take it from there. You're responsible for turning the substrings into the right type, and putting them in the right places.

Comment: Yes there is a way. I would recommend using substring

Comment: I would recommend using Scanner with a preset delimiter.

Comment: Did you try json parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do the following:

```
String s = "[[0,0,2,0],[0,0,2,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]";

String myNums[] = s.split("[^0-9]+");
//Split at every non-digit

int my_array[][] = new int[4][4];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        my_array[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(myNums[i*4 + j + 1]);
        //The 1 accounts for the extra "" at the beginning.
    }
}

//Prints the result
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        System.out.print(my_array[i][j]);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: or as a single loop `for(int i=0; i<myNums.length(); i++)` with `my_array[i%4][i/4] = Integer.parseInt(myNums[i]);`

Comment: `.split`... just what I thought about.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to to it dynamically, I've written a librray: https://github.com/timaschew/MDAAJ
The nice thing is, that it's really fast, because internally it's a one dimensional array, but provides you same access and much more nice features, checkout the [wiki](https://github.com/timaschew/MDAAJ/wiki) and and [tests](https://github.com/timaschew/MDAAJ/blob/master/src/test/java/de/unikassel/mdda/MDDATest.java)

```
MDDA<Integer> array = new MDDA<Integer>(4,4);
```

or initialize with an existing array, which is one dimensional "template", but will be converted into your dimensions:

```
Integer[] template = new Integer[] {0,0,2,0,  0,0,2,0,  0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0};
MDDA<Integer> array = new MDDA<Integer>(template, false, 4,4);

//instead of array[1][2];
array.get(1,2); // 2
```